# How to make JS imports writable?

Tags: javascript, import

I'm going through a GraphQL tutorial, and to make things cleaner and leaner I put the data into a separate file called `fakeData.js` exporting the variables to my main `index.js` file where the logic resides.

I've made my exports, each of them being an array of objects (e.g. `user`, `posts`, `comments`), from `const` to `let` to be able to modify them, but realized this only works when they're in the main file, not as imports where it shows `SyntaxError: user/posts/comments is read-only`.

A delete function in the main file tries to modify the import itself, for example, `comments` using filter method.

Is there any way to make imports writable and get them out of being read-only?

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like:

```
import mockData from './fakeData.js'

const activeUsers = mockData.users.filter(user => user.active);
```